# Proper way to fetch two attributes in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an entity named `Route` and two attributes from that entity named `Longitude` and `Latitude`.
The function of the App is simple: It will fetch the data from `Longitude` and `Latitude` and create a NSArray.

For Example:

```
 Route 1 has Longitude=2 and Latitude=41
 Route 2 has Longitude=3 and Latitude=42
 Route 3 has Longitude=4 and Latitude=43
```

So the Result will be a NSArray with that content:

```
{ 
   [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:41 longitude:2],
   [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:42 longitude:3],
   [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:43 longitude:4],
}
```

But the problem is if I fetch both attributes from different setupFetchedResultsController I can't "connect" them with their appropriate partner (I'll get 2 separated list of values). Is there another way to fetch data from 2 attributes "connected"?

This is one of my `fetchedResultsController` if anyone needs to see:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedLatitudController
{
    if (_fetchedLatitudController != nil) {
        return _fetchedLatitudController;
    }

    // 1 - Decide what Entity you want
    NSString *entityName = @"Route"; // Put your entity name here

    // 2 - Request that Entity
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];


    // 4 - Sort it if you want
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"latitude"
                                                                                     ascending:YES
                                                                                      selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
    // 5 - Fetch it
    self.fetchedLatitudController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
    [self.fetchedLatitudController performFetch:nil];

    return _fetchedLatitudController;
}
```

Comment: Please show your code. How do you fetch the attributes?

Comment: I use the common template of setupfetchedResultsController to fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use *two* fetched results controllers. A fetched results controller
(by default) fetches objects of your managed object subclass, which you can then query
for all attributes. For example:

```
Route *route = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSNumber *lng = route.longitude;
NSNumber *lat = route.latitude;
```

But note that a fetched results controller is typically used with a table view (or
collection view). If you just want to create an array then you can execute a simple
fetch request instead:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Route"];
NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
    // Some error occurred ...
} else {
    for (Route *route in fetchedObjects) {
        NSNumber *lng = route.longitude;
        NSNumber *lat = route.latitude;
        CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[lat doubleValue] longitude:[lng doubleValue]];
        // ... add loc to your array ...
    }
}
```

If the "Route" entity has *many* attributes, then it might be more efficient to
set

```
 [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
 [request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"longitude", @"latitude"]];
```

to fetch only the attributes that your are interested in. Then `fetchedObjects` is
an array of *dictionaries*, from which you can create the `CLLocation`s.

Comment: My answer assumes that the attributes have lower-case names ("longitude", "latitude") which is more common.